# How to quickly get started with Isabelle's formal language standard to formally describe modeling language？

Tags: model, transformation, isabelle, formal-languages, formal-verification

I am currently working on solving the problem of **correctness of model transformations**. I read a lot of articles and found Isabelle theorem prover is a good choice to solve the problem. Now I want to use the Isabelle theorem prover for analysis and verification. But I do not know how to formalize my modeling language (including source model, target model, transformation itself) with **Isabelle ’s own language standard**. In other words, I want to quickly learn Isabelle's **formal language** to describe my modeling language. I downloaded many documentation on the official website, but I can not determined how to get started quickly. I hope that researchers in the field can give some suggestions to the beginners, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend the concrete semantics book:

http://concrete-semantics.org/

It teaches you how to model a small programming language in Isabelle and how to specify its semantics.

I guess the approach will be similar for a modeling language.

1.Describe the abstract syntax of source and target language using algebraic data types.
2. Define the semantics for both. 
3. Define transformations as functions.